# NSURLRequest cache issue iOS 7

Tags: ios7, nsurlrequest, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

in iOS 7 cachePolicy doesn't work, it just cache the downloaded json.

```
//URLRequest
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.semhora.com/jsonparser/categories/categories_%d_test.json", _categoriesIndex];
        NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

How can I disallow cache in iOS 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just used:

```
//URLRequest
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.semhora.com/jsonparser/categories/categories_%d_test.json", _categoriesIndex];
        NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                  cachePolicy:0
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

And now it works, got any answer from apple dev forum until now why it happens.

Comment: should this block or allow caching?

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem and I verified that setting `cachePolicy = 0`  instead of `cachePolicy = NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` fixes the problem.

This doesn't make sense to me either since 0 corresponds to `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed`.
We can't just set it to 0 since Apple will probably fix this in a future release.
You might try calling:

`[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:yourRequest]` just before initiating the request.

UPDATE:
After further research I found that the code that broke has been using the wrong enum.  Take a look at NSURLRequestCachePolicy in NSURLRequest.h.  That's the one you need and it explains why setting to 0 fixed the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

The correct enum for the cache Policy is :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
```

If you are over 3G, some provider use caching even if you disable it in your `NSMutableURLRequest`, so if the cache policy doesn't work set the HTTP header field cache-control to no-cache.

```
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"cache-control"];
```

Comment: Be aware that as of iOS 8.1, the cache policy `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is still unimplemented as described in the NSURLRequest header file in the Foundation framework.